# Recirculating Pump Question

Tags: shower, pump

We recently completed a master bath remodel project. Part of that project involved running a separate hot and cold supply line for the walk in shower. Additionally, we opted to add a recirculation pump and dedicated return loop line to reduce the time to get hot water for the shower. The issue we are having is that unless the recirculation pump is running, the water temp in the shower is only getting up to 95F at max hot. The hot water in the rest of the house is 125F at max hot with the pump off. A bit of research shows that this might need a check valve(s)? Appreciate any insight on this issue.

Happy to provide additional images or info.
[link to photos](https://ibb.co/album/TKF4sz)

Comment: recirculating pump is recirculating, when and how does it get fresh hot water in the loop

Answer (score 2):

based on the above, yes you'll need a check valve so that the shower draws hot water only from the hot supply side of the loop, and not from the return side.

Answer (score 0):

Im not clear of the 'circuit diagram' for the water lines.... but with a recirc pump WITH a dedicated return line, there is no need for special valves in the baths/shower.

Just run hot and cold to the shower...  put a T at the shower with a return line back to the recirc pump.  pump then dumps the water back into the tank.  Pump should have a check valve in it.  I like a thermostatically controlled pump (turns off when it sees hot water back at tank.  Maybe add a timer to it as well.  This way it is only running until hot water 'fills' the loop.

Post a circuit diagram WITH part numbers for the Watts items....